# Can't enter BIOS after drive compression

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bios, compression

So I decided to compress everything on my main drive which was a horrible idea.

[image]

Now I can't enter my BIOS anymore. I tried:

- Pressing keys on startup
- Running `shutdown /s /fw` in cmd but I get this error `Boot to firmware UI is not supported by this system's firmware.(1)`
- Unchecking the "Compress this drive to save space" checkbox (which took like 24 hours and most of my files still have that blue compressed icon on them, so maybe the decompression failed?)

Any idea what is wrong and how I can fix this so that I can enter my BIOS on startup? I could startup to my BIOS by pressing keys just fine, but after the compression I can't enter my BIOS anymore. The compression is definitely the problem (I think)

Comment: I think you'd better save your files and install Windows again. If you still have a mechanical disk, you can take the opportunity to replace it with an SSD

Comment: Haha thanks but obviously I would like to try everything else before doing that

Comment: Entering BIOS is not relative to drive compression. At all. "After" is not equal to "because of".

Comment: @Akina Well for a front end user perspective I clicked the compress files checkbox and `after` OR `because of` my BIOS stopped working as it should. Regardless of your view that `action` caused my problem.